# how to pass data from not-main activity to thread

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I created object bluetooth-service, where was thread created, which monitors data in queue. From main-activity was one activity created, where i can set data. How i can pass data from this activity to thread for sending messages, withount passing object bluetooth-service?

Comment: Show us your correspondening code and show us where you are struggeling. We will try to help you but we won't code a full website for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you think about using a static class that would save the message you need to send, then maybe use the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (if needed) for notifying the thread it has a new message to send

Comment: I can pass object this static class from main activity to second activity through intent?

Comment: no, since the class is static (think about using Singleton)  you only need to get the instance everytime (static meaning : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) and then ask for the value like `Singleton.getInstance().getValue()`

Comment: if the response suit to your problem /or not let me know

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus for that. This will simplify the code. All you need to do is [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md). In your case you need to:

1. Add graddle dependency

   `compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'`
2. create event class:

   ```
   public class MessageEvent {
      public final String message; 
      public YourObject object;//use what you need here to pass data.

      public MessageEvent(String message) {
         this.message = message;
         ...
      }
   }
   ```
3. Create Subscribers:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
      EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
      super.onStop();
   }

   // This method will be called when a MessageEvent is posted
   public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){
      Toast.makeText(context, event.message,     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   // This method will be called when a SomeOtherEvent is posted
   public void onEvent(SomeOtherEvent event){
       doSomethingWith(event);
   }
   ```
4. And finally post your data:

   ```
   EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("Hello everyone!"));
   ```

Let me know if this helped.